# String not getting converted to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have I have Excel file from where I am getting date in string format as "30-12-1899 07:50:00:AM"

When I am trying to convert it to `DATETIME` then it is giving error as

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

I am trying to convert it like this

```
Convert.ToDateTime(homeToSchool[7],new DateTimeFormatInfo { ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", DateSeparator = "-" })
```

Comment: Your pattern `dd-MM-yyyy` does not match your input. A correct pattern would be `dd-MM-yyyy hh:ss:mm tt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
string myDate = "30-12-1899 07:50:00:AM";
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:tt", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

For more information about Date and Time Format Strings,

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Wow ! ! i guess Dejavu == duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading this from excel I hope this would help

```
 DateTime.FromOADate(homeToSchool[7].ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```